# Binomial distribution with loc parameter in pymc3

Tags: python, distribution, pymc3, mixture-model

I would like to use a Binomial distribution that is shifted by the parameter `loc` (as in [`scipy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binom.html)) in a pymc3 model.
E.g.:

```py
with pm.Model() as m1:
    prob = pm.Beta('prob',alpha=2,beta=2)
    x = pm.Binomial('x',n=20,p=prob,loc=5)
```

But `Binomial` does not allow for a shift parameter.

I tried to build it myself following the various tutorials on pymc3's website, but without success (I am very much a beginner in using pymc3 and theano). My latest attempt (probably very bad)

```py
... 
from scipy.stats import binom

class BinoShift(pm.Discrete):
    def __init__(self, n, p, x, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BinoShift, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.n = n
        self.p = p
        self.mode = np.round(n*p)
        self.shift = x

    def logp(self, value):
        n = self.n
        p = self.p
        shift = self.shift
        return binom.logpmf(value,n,p,loc=shift)
```

**Backround**: I have observations on random variable `X = X_0 + z` where `z` is a unobserved latent variable, `X_0` is unobserved and Binomially distributed with (`N-z,p`) with `N` known. Final goal is to obtain a posterior distribution over `p` and `z`. This corresponds pretty much to a mixture model problem with unobserved cluster assignments. `X \sim \sum_z p(z)(z + Bino(p,N-z))`. So if I had the binomial distribution with a shift parameter the pymc3 model that I envision looks something like

```py
# generate data; kept simple here, but N and z may actually differ across sample 
size = 500
N = 20
p = 0.7
z = 5

X = np.random.binomial(N-z,p,size=size) + z

with pm.Model() as mixture:
    prob = pm.Beta('prob',alpha=2,beta=2)

    weight = pm.Dirichlet('weight',a=np.array([1]*N))
    comp = [pm.Binomial('X_{}'.format(i),n=N-i,p=prob,loc=i) for i in range(N)]
    like = pm.Mixture('like',w=weight,comp_dists=comp,observed=X)
```

Other ways I tried to build this problem into a pymc3 model included a hierachical model with final line referring to the distribution of `X_0` given the other paramters/unkowns, which is simply the Binomial distribution. But then I wouldn't how to pass as "observed" values, X-z. Another way I thought of was to first define the distributions of `z` and `X_0` and then use `pm.Deterministic` for `B`. But the deterministic class does not accept observed values (I guess as it would not know how to evaluate the likelihood).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy-pasted the source code by pymc3 and added the loc parameter (changes are marked):

```py
import numpy as np
import theano.tensor as tt

from pymc3.distributions.dist_math import bound, binomln, logpow
from pymc3.math import tround
from pymc3.theanof import floatX, intX
from pymc3.distributions.distribution import Discrete

class BinoShift(Discrete):

    def __init__(self, n, p, loc, *args, **kwargs): # <---
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.n = n = tt.as_tensor_variable(intX(n))
        self.loc = loc = tt.as_tensor_variable(intX(loc)) # <--- 
        self.p = p = tt.as_tensor_variable(floatX(p))
        self.mode = tt.cast(tround(n * p), self.dtype)


    def logp(self, value):
        n = self.n
        p = self.p
        loc = self.loc # <---

        k = value-loc # <---
        return bound(
            binomln(n, k) + logpow(p, k) + logpow(1 - p, n - k),
            0 <= k, k <= n,
            0 <= p, p <= 1) # <---
```